# Using webpack on the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I am trying to make a node back-end service using express and I want to use webpack too to bundle everything in a single file (don't know if it makes sense, I'm just learning). I set up my `package.json` this way:

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

this is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const backend = {
  name: 'backend',
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  externals: [nodeExternals],
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  }
};

module.exports = [backend];
module.exports.plugins = [
  new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({})
];
```

and this is my `src/index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var httpsrv = express();

httpsrv.get("/", function(res, rep) {
  console.log("inside get.");
  rep.send("<div>hey js!</div>");
});

httpsrv.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("server started.");
});
```

Pretty basic, isn't it? When I build and run (`node ./bin/app.js`) the app everything is fine, it behaves as expected, but something sounds me strange. The `app.js` file is too short to bundle the `express` library, and when I put my `app.js` into a `node:alpine` container I get this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- /app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app.js:1:1134)
    at n (/app.js:1:110)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app.js:1:958)
    at n (/app.js:1:110)
    at /app.js:1:902
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app.js:1:911) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/app.js' ]
}
```

So I'm not getting what I want: a web service in a single file. What's wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to webpack your server-side code? I'm not seeing why you need it

Comment: I would advise against doing so. I thought about doing it about my own project previously, and the loss sacrifice in debugging isn't worth the negligible performance gain you're probably seeking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you're setting the `externals` option.

This is from the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's (any end-user application) environment. This feature is typically most useful to library developers, however there are a variety of applications for it.

Also from the [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) NPM page:

> `externals: [nodeExternals()],` // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder

If you really want to include some (or all) of or dependencies into your webpack output, you'd want to change or remove that option.

Answer (score 4):

The point of having a module bundler is mainly delivering a smaller bundle size to the client. Given that your code will be executed from the server side and what's sent to the client is just the response for whatever request they made it doesn't really make sense for someone who's just learning to set up Webpack for a backend project.

You can still do it if you are interested in using some Javascript flavor you can get by sending your code through a transpiler such as Babel but I don't think this is the case.

Regarding the error: the reason seems to be that you have set the `externals` property to exclude your `nodeExternals` and that is where your `express` dependency is located.